# How can I display the layout containing the buttons down on the screen

Tags: android

With the layout below the buttons are being **shown on top of the page**.  How can I make them appear below, after the container, **down on the page**?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/Main"
            android:onClick="ClickHomePage"
            android:text= "@string/Home"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:onClick="ClickClients"
            android:text= "@string/Clients"
            >

        </Button>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The MainActivity looks as follows and the HomePage.xml is also below

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
             {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            GetButtonClicked(5);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }



        public void GetButtonClicked(int position)
        {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments

            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position){ 
                case 0:
                    fragment= new FirstPageFragment();
                    break;

                default:
                    fragment =  new FirstPageFragment();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        public  void ClickHomePage(View view){
            GetButtonClicked(0);
        }
        public  void ClickClients(View view){
            GetButtonClicked();
        }

        }




   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.test.FirstPageFragment" android:background="@drawable/theme">
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the FirstPage

```
public class FirstPageFragment extends Fragment {


public FirstPageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first_page, container, false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not include the container in another layout...

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.MainPageActivityActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/container">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/container">
and insert buttons layout here....
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/Main"
            android:onClick="ClickHomePage"
            android:text= "@string/Home"
           />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ralative layout insted of linear.

Answer (score 0):

Make a different layout for bottom buttons, and then at the last of your container layout use this:

```
<include android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottom_buttons"/>
```

Comment: even with a different layout the buttons are not visible.  The container fills all the space

Comment: add **android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"** in your container layout

Comment: even with this, the buttons are not visible

Comment: You are using Linear Layout as your container layout, which place its child in Top to Bottom manner, You should use Relative Layout as your container layout, and then use my ans, your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Use RelativeLayout with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` step by step guide is available [here](http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=334).

Your skeleton for layout should look like this

```
<RelativeLayout

           <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

              <Button
              <Button

           </LinearLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Final Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="ClickHomePage"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="ClickClients"
        android:text="Clients" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With relative layout, I can`t see the buttons anymore

Comment: @even with this I can`t see the buttons below.  It is only showing the content in the container and buttons are not there

Comment: @user4657208 updated answer, I bet you do not have strings Home and Clients under your strings.xml

Comment: The new code does not help either, I still can`t see the buttons on the screen

Comment: The code I have provided initially shows the buttons up on the screen, but I want them to be down

Comment: @user4657208 Have you seen the attached snapshot. Is this you want?

Comment: yes, the buttons should be at the bottom below the container, as add other fragments in the container

Comment: I have found that the container should have been in another layout.  Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="ClickHomePage"
        android:text="@string/Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="ClickClients"
        android:text="@string/Clients" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try this